# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord' (details below)

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-module, discord.py

So I am trying to install the discord API wrapper for discord and I am not sure if it is in the wrong pathway or what. Everything I try to import discord it gives the error above.

How I verified pip was installed and then installed discord:

```
moro@Falco123:~$ sudo apt-get install  python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 222 not upgraded.
moro@Falco123:~$ pip3 install -U discord.py
Collecting discord.py
Collecting aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0 (from discord.py)
  Using cached aiohttp-1.0.5-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting websockets<4.0,>=3.1 (from discord.py)
  Using cached websockets-3.3-py33.py34.py35.py36-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet (from aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0->discord.py)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting async-timeout (from aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0->discord.py)
  Using cached async_timeout-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting multidict>=2.0 (from aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0->discord.py)
  Using cached multidict-3.1.3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: chardet, async-timeout, multidict, aiohttp, 
websockets, discord.py
Successfully installed aiohttp-1.0.5 async-timeout-1.2.1 chardet-3.0.4 
discord.py-0.16.8 multidict-3.1.3 websockets-3.3
moro@Falco123:~$ python3.6
Python 3.6.2 (default, Aug 16 2017, 16:00:27)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import discord
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
>>> exit()
```

I also tried the method on the official python documentation page and nothing:

```
moro@Falco123:~$ python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip
moro@Falco123:~$ sudo python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
[sudo] password for moro:
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

The main issue is that I want to install the discord module to use in my python scripts. I also checked to see if discord was in any of the python3 modules lists using "help('modules')" inside both the default ubuntu python3.5 and the python 3.6 I installed. It was not listed. Feel free to request additional commands or information

EDIT:

```
moro@Falco123:/usr/bin$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
moro@Falco123:/usr/bin$
```

EDIT:

```
moro@Falco123:~$ python3.6 -m pip install discord.py
/usr/local/bin/python3.6: No module named pip
moro@Falco123:~$
```

EDIT:

I installed python by downloading python 3.6.2 from the official site, then i extracted, compiled it, and installed it with the following commands:

```
cd Downloads/
cd Python-3.6.2/
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

EDIT: when I compiled python I did not compile it with SSL. For future people with this issue see here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/331
Also to add the SSL look here at roughly half way through when he starts to install it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4nPFZCf-wM

Comment: which version of python is your pip3 installation associated with? `pip3 -V`

Comment: alternatively, do you perhaps already have a folder named `discord` in your project directory? https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/228#issuecomment-267801097

Comment: @Hamms well that is probably the issue but how can I install pip for python3.6? the output is above. Ad for the folder theory, I literally just installed ubuntu and my test.py file is in documents with no discord folder

Comment: Your `pip3` is for Python 3.5, but you're running 3.6 as your main version. Try `python3.6 -m pip install discord.py`.

Comment: @Hamms output is above

Comment: Since `pip` is in the `python3/dist-packages` directory, python3.6 should be able to find it and `python3.6 -m pip` should work fine. It could be the case that your python3.6 installation is weird; did you do anything out of the ordinary to set it up?

Comment: @Hamms all the commands I used are above, the guide I saw compiled it from source and I did it before so thats what I did again

Comment: @Hamms hey man thanks for the help in the right direction, as said in the question i figured it out mate. Cheers!

Comment: I would in the future recommend installing from the `apt` repositories first, before trying to install manually